# Smooth extension of the angle function $\theta(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, differential-forms

Consider the vector field
\begin{align}
F:\ \mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}&\longrightarrow\mathbb R^2
\\ (x,y)&\longmapsto F(x,y)=\left(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right)
\end{align}
We know that $F$ has a potential function
$$\theta(x,y)=\arctan\frac{y}{x},\ x\ne0$$
which is also known as $\textbf{angle function}$.
I wonder if $\theta$ could be extended to a smooth function on $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. So where should I start ? Could anyone hint me some solid idea ? Thanks

Comment: Well what happens when you approach $(0,\infty)\times\{0\}$ from above and from below?

Comment: what do you meant approach from above and from below ?

Comment: It almost works, but there has to be a branch cut somewhere. The comment above is suggesting the positive $x$ axis, where the angle would approach $0$ "from above" and once going around the origin once counterclockwise would approach $2\pi$ "from below". You can make the ray of discontinuity point out in another direction (e.g. the negative $x$ axis is a common choice), but you can't get rid of it.

Comment: The idea is that when you go around the origin once your angle will change by $2\pi$, so there is no way to make it continuous on the entire punctured plane (otherwise you'd get the contradiction $0=2\pi$, as by going around the origin once you'd change your angle by $2\pi$ while still ending up at the same point)

Comment: Notice that your function doesn't do what you want even when $x\ne 0$. What are its values in quadrants II and III?